# Proving a matrix identity: if $Z = VT^{-1}V^T$, then $ (I - Z + Z(I + Z)^{-1}Z)^{-1} = I + Z $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm walking through a [least squares derivation for the Kalman Filter](http://kom.aau.dk/~borre/kalman/lecture4/lec4.pdf), and after several hours I'm still unable to derive the statement made on page 15. In particular, that for a  matrix $Z = VT^{-1}V^T$,

$$
(I - Z + Z(I + Z)^{-1}Z)^{-1} = I + Z
$$

I've been attempting to use the [Woodbury Matrix Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) to no avail. Is this obvious to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just verify
$$(I+Z)(I-Z + Z(I+Z)^{-1} Z) = I - Z^2 + Z^2 = I$$

Answer (score 0):

To flesh out Robert's answer,

$$
\begin{align*}
 & (I+Z)(I-Z+Z(I+Z)^{-1}Z) \\
=& (I - Z + Z(I+Z)^{-1}Z) + (Z - Z^2 + Z^2(I+Z)^{-1}Z) \\
=& \, I - Z^2 + Z(I+Z)(I+Z)^{-1}Z \\
=& \, I
\end{align*}
$$

I failed to notice that $Z(I+Z)^{-1}Z + Z^2 (I+Z)^{-1}Z = Z (I+Z)(I+Z)^{-1} Z = Z^2$ when originally attempting to derive this identity.